# Notation for Composition and product of a function

Tags: functions, notation

I am confused about notation for composition and products of a function $f$. I know that $f \circ f$ implies composition but how we will denote product of same function and whether there is another way to write $f \circ f$?

Comment: write parentheses if unsure which goes first, $(f\circ f) g = f(f)\cdot g$, $f\circ (g\cdot f) = f(g\cdot f)$

Answer (score 2):

The product of $f$ with itself is $f.f$, $f\times f$, or $f^2$.

Comment: This would be a better Answer if you gave the contrast between notation for the product of $f$ with itself versus the composition of $f$ with itself.

Comment: Okay sir thanks and is there any other notation for  (fof) ?

Comment: @alearner Yes: $f^{(2)}$. More generally, the composition of $f$ with itself $n$ times is denoted by $f^{(n)}$.

Comment: Okay sir but _f^(n)_ can be used to denote n times differentiation of a function ,isn't it?

Comment: @alearner I am sorry. I made a mistake. You are right about $f^{(n)}$. The standard notation for $f$ composed with itself $n$ times is $f^n$. Of course, in a context in which $f$ can be *multiplied* with itself you will have to be careful.

Comment: So finally what we can conclude about notation ?

Comment: If $f$ is a function from, say, $\mathbb Z$ to itself, $f^2$ could be $f\circ f$ or $f\times f$, depending on the context.